# keep focus on text input field if another input field is not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an onblur event where any time some one clicks anywhere on the page it will stay focused on that element unless it is a specif element then it will refocus to that specific element.
I am probably way off but this is what I tried, and it just stays focused on the Barcode element no matter what.

```
function stayOnBarcode() {
    var QTY = document.getElementById("QTY");
    var Barcode = document.getElementById("Barcode");
    if (Barcode.value === "") {
        if (QTY.focus() === true) {
            QTY.focus();
        }
        else if (document.hasFocus() === true) {
            Barcode.focus();
        }
    }
    else {
        Barcode.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you make your input focus on page load than it will remain focus unless you click on any other input or a link, is that how you want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
    clicked = $(e.target)
})

$("input").on("blur", function() {
    if (!clicked.is("#QTY") && !clicked.is("#Barcode")) {
        $(this).focus()
    }
})
```

It stores the most recently clicked element in the variable `clicked`, then on `blur` event it checks if `last_clicked` is something other than `#QTY` or `#Barcode`. If so, it re-focuses the `input` being blurred.

You might need to tweak it to fit the exact conditions you have in mind, or feel free to add specifics to your question.

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oez0488h/63/

Comment: That looks great!  For some reason when I try and implement this it doesn't work. Do I have to add this to an onload somehow? or onclick or something?

Comment: @Tommy Graffam Are you running a JQuery file? If you've got JQuery loaded up properly, just do the following to make sure everything runs on load:  `$(document).ready (function () { \\add entire code in here})`

Comment: Okay so this works great in chrome!! But it isn't working in firefox, or IE and the console in firefox doesn't tell me anything and the console in IE says 'focused' is undefined. Also I need to get this code to work in Windows Mobile 5 IE which is similar to IE6 i believe. Are there any suggestions on this?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this?